# Falling dominoes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-velocity

I have been attempting to determine the maximum velocity a line of dominoes can reach. 
I have found that there are two forces which act upon it: Initial impulse and gravitational force.

As kinetic energy is not conserved eventually gravitational force becomes the main force so the velocity becomes almost constant. So I have been trying to find a formula to determine the gravitational potential energy, and found the following formula

$$H_n(θ_n) =\sum_1^n \left[\cos\theta_i+ (d/h)\sin\theta_i\right]$$

It was on http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0401018

I was wondering how this was calculated as general potential energy is equal to $m*g*h$

Comment: Hi user43087. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could define the notation used. As written one cannot guess some of the symbols, and specifically I wonder how you speak of energy without the mass or gravitational acceleration coming into it... Can you dig a little deeper into the paper and explain more fully (links disappear - your question need to be able to stand on its own). I think this could become quite interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding this is the phrase

> The potential part derives
>   from the combined height of the center of mass of the falling dominoes, for which we
>   take the dimensionless quantity

Followed by the equation:

$$H_n(\theta_n)=\sum_i^n{\left[\cos\theta_i + (d/h)\sin\theta_i\right]}$$

In other words - this is describing the equivalent height of the center of mass of each of the $n$ dominoes given their respective angles $\theta_i$. You can get this by drawing yourself a simple diagram: the first term is the height of the center of mass for an infinitesimally thin  domino, and the second term is a correction for the finite width. But it's a "dimensionless" quantity: it has been normalized by dividing by the original height $h$ of the domino. If you were to draw the picture of a single domino, the height you would get for a given angle would be

$$H = (h/2)\cos\theta + (d/2)\sin\theta$$

And the factors 2, like the terms $g$ and $m$, are "ignored" because this is describing a dimensionless approach (something that will scale with the problem, regardless of actual dimensions and mass).

Getting from there to energy requires multiplication by $mg$ but that doesn't change the basic dynamics, just the scaling.